# What's a good quote from Chazal to use as a constant reminder?

Tags: talmud-gemara, quotations, chazal

I am looking for some of Mi Yodeya's favorite quotes from Mishna, Gemara, works of Chazal, etc. that can be used as constant reminders to always be doing the right thing and trying to grow.

I am aware this is an open-ended question, with many ways to interpret, but that's part of the idea - I am looking for quotes that anyone may use a daily reminder to help them grow and be better!

Comment: Shulchan Aruch 1:1

Comment: Second to last passuk in Koheles

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quote I like: "Who is rich?  He who is happy with his lot." Ben Zoma — Pirkei Avos 4:1.

Answer (score 4):

[Pirkei Avot 1:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.14?lang=bi):

> הוּא הָיָה אוֹמֵר, אִם אֵין אֲנִי לִי, מִי לִי. וּכְשֶׁאֲנִי לְעַצְמִי, מָה אֲנִי.) **וְאִם לֹא עַכְשָׁיו, אֵימָתָי**):
>
> (He used to say: If I am not for myself, who is for me? But if I am for my own self, what am I?) **And if not now, when**?

Answer (score 4):

למד לשונך לומר איני יודע

Teach your tongue to say: “I do not know”.

(Talmud, Berakhot 4a)

(Framed on the wall in my study.)

Comment: Maybe hang up 25b for good measure

Comment: This is a very wise qoute.

Answer (score 2):

אל תאמר לכשאפנה אשנה, שמא לא תפנה

Do not say "When I have am available I shall study," lest you never become available.

(משנה, פרקי אבות ב:ה)

---

כֹּ֣ה ׀ אָמַ֣ר יְהֹוָ֗ה אַל־יִתְהַלֵּ֤ל חָכָם֙ בְּחכְמָת֔וֹ וְאַל־יִתְהַלֵּ֥ל הַגִּבּ֖וֹר בִּגְבֽוּרָת֑וֹ אַל־יִתְהַלֵּ֥ל עָשִׁ֖יר בְּעשְׁרֽוֹ׃
כִּ֣י אִם־בְּזֹ֞את יִתְהַלֵּ֣ל הַמִּתְהַלֵּ֗ל הַשְׂכֵּל֮ וְיָדֹ֣עַ אוֹתִי֒ כִּ֚י אֲנִ֣י יְהֹוָ֔ה עֹ֥שֶׂה חֶ֛סֶד מִשְׁפָּ֥ט וּצְדָקָ֖ה בָּאָ֑רֶץ כִּֽי־בְאֵ֥לֶּה חָפַ֖צְתִּי נְאֻם־יְהֹוָֽה׃

Thus said the Lord:
Let not the wise man glory in his wisdom;
Let not the strong man glory in his strength;
Let not the rich man glory in his riches.
But only in this should one glory:
In his earnest devotion to Me.
For I the Lord act with kindness,
Justice, and equity in the world;
For in these I delight
—declares the Lord.